# How to access Visual Studio Code extension settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

Got myself Visual Studio Code. I've installed a `Uncrustify` extension to make my files be formatted when I edit them. I wanted to make it format my files on save, but I cannot open like Options menu for this extension or something like that. The author gives this screenshot:

[image]

But I cannot reach that menu. When I click on this little gear circle near the extension under the Extensions tab, it just pops up a menu with: `Disable (Workspace)`, `Disable (Always)`, `Uninstall`. I can only edit 4 things, like my `.cfg` file path under `Ctrl+Comma` settings, but that's not what I am searching for, and it's not what is on this screen provided by author

I guess I am not only asking about this particular extension, but generally for extension settings in this editor.

Answer (score 16):

Many ways mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25012#issuecomment-295407589) in an issue created available on VSCode repository: [Allow to change settings from Extensions editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25012).

On Windows, I could be able to change settings by going to:

> File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions.

Comment: I installed Slugify extension but I cannot find any settings for it in `File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions`. How do I create new settings?

Comment: @ArvindK. In that case, you can write your own settings manually inside `settings.json`. You can reach that file by clicking on `CTRL + SHIFT + P` inside the VS code editor and type `settings`, then click on `preferences -> Open User Settings` and write your own settings.

`settings.json` file is inside `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`. This defines special settings for the current Windows user either for the editor itself or for installed extensions.

Comment: Re: _settings.json file is inside C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json. This defines special settings for the current Windows user either for the editor itself or for installed extensions._ That was the perfect solution for Windows 7 that I was looking for - thank you, @MohammedAlBanna !!

Answer (score -1):

Dont know if you figured it out yet or not but maybe for someone who comes here to find an answer.

Step 1: Press `ctrl`+`alt`+`p` to open the command pallet.

Step 2: Search and execute this command `Uncrustify: Open config file`

If your config file has not been created, then before step 2 you must execute `Uncrustify: Create default config file` command.

Anyways, these instructions are present their in `Details` section of the extension.

Comment: Where do you execute `Uncrustify: Create default config file`?

Comment: Once you get VS Code up and running, you may execute this command just by pressign `ctrl + shift + p`